# Strange file corruptions in ext4

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, ext4, corruption

Recently I came in contact with what appears to be disk corruption scenarios, and I would like to understand them better.

I have a build server which I work with daily. During one full build of a recent LLVM release which stopped with a strange error message, I got this excerpt for one generated file (`X86GenDisassemblerTables.inc`):

```
...
/* 0xa5 */
{ /* ModRMDecision */
 MODRM_ONEENTRY,
 0 /* EmptyTable */
},
/* 0xa6 */
{ /* ModRMDecision */
 MODÒM_ONEENTRY,                # Ò = 0xD2
 0 /* EmptyTable */             # R = 0x52
},
/* 0xa7 */
{ /* ModRMDecision */
 MODRM_ONEENTRY,
 0 /* EmptyTable */
},
...
```

This seems to be a single-bit file corruption. I removed the file, the build generated it again and completed successfully.

And today, in a *different* machine, this `.d` file was produced during a build:

```
output-gcc-8.2.0-x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/headers.hpp.gch: src/headers.hpp
pp      # What's this?
```

Everything else -- file size, permissions, even the terminating newline -- was in place. Removing the file also allowed the build to generate it again without problems.

Are these legitimate cases of disk corruption? Which tools can I use to diagnose this? These disks are, respectively, one and two-year old SSDs running ext4 file systems.

Comment: No, that's RAM failure, not disk corruption.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to start with a RAM test. Hard dives typically know when they have a read or write failure. If you're not already receiving hard drive errors in the kernel messages and you're not using ECC RAM, I would suspect the RAM over the hard drive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suspected it might have been the RAM also. Although it doesn't have ECC chips, the server went through a three-day memory test a couple of years ago before deployment, so I ruled out the possibility of RAM corruption in the short term (since lifespans of memory chips are quite long). I will definitely run a battery of memory tests in this other machine I've mentioned in the question.